# Parameters containing spaces not parsed correctly when used from string variable

Tags: bash

I've got some options for commands stored in variable.
Unfortunately whenever there is a space bash treats that as variable separator despite string being in quotes.

I am aware, that proper way of doing it is using arrays in bash, but this situation I've encountered is based on legacy scripts which are deploying code on commit in git. Unfortunately I have to stay with string-in-variable solution, which was doing fine till there was a need to use space in one of arguments (take a look on example, there is `--filter='- /logs/'` parameter.

Example script:

```
#!/bin/bash

RSYNC_OPTS="-r --delete --exclude .env --filter='- /logs/' --links"
mkdir a b
rsync $RSYNC_OPTS a b
```

I got following error:

> Unknown filter rule: `'-' rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1)
>   at exclude.c(927) [client=3.1.3]

As far as I understand, space after `--filter='-` acted like argument separator despite being used in single quotes.

Until now I tried:

- quote mode for variable: `${RSYNC_OPTS@Q}`
- Escaping space or single quotes in `RSYNC_OPTS` variable
- Changing single quotes with double ones

How to make bash interpret string in quote properly when sending it as  string in variable? I hope that there will be solution that does not involve changing RSYNC_OPTS to something else than single string text variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `"$RSYNC_OPTS"` (suppress globbing) and also use `eval`, eg :

```
eval rsync "$RSYNC_OPTS" a b
```

Comment: Have you tried your answer? I've provided example script for testing purposes and it seems that  `"$RSYNC_OPTS"` is treated as single argument to rsync and resulting in `unknown option` error

Comment: try with eval as per updated answer

Comment: See [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/4154375).

Answer (score 4):

For such cases, bash arrays is the proper solution.

```
RSYNC_OPTS=(-r --delete --exclude .env --filter='- /logs/' --links)
rsync "${RSYNC_OPTS[@]}" a b
```

Comment: Yeah. I know, but I am getting those options as string from: `$(git config --get "deploy.${branch}.opts)` as a string. Although thank you for your input.